# How to monitor Google Kubernetes Services (ingress,https endpoint, ClusterIP, nodeport, Load balancers)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, stackdriver

We are setting up monitoring for all kinds of GKE objects like (pods, services, persist storages, custom parameters for Kafka, Redis, cronjob, etc. )

We are able to monitor the globally exposed endpoints like ingress and https endpoints with [uptime checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks). However, how we can monitor the services which are clusterIP, nodeport or load balancers as most of are not globally exposed.

My questions:

1) Is it necessary to monitor all the services which are clusterIP, nodeport or load balancer?

2) If yes, can you please suggest the reference article or steps for it?

**Note:** Cluster has ISTIO and Google workload identity enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure monitoring as per your requirement.

You can use [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) with [alert manager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/) to post a message in slack.

[Uptime robot](https://uptimerobot.com/) for notification via call.

[Google uptime check](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks) notify via Emails.

It's not necessary to check all the endpoints unless business logic affecting & breaking.

**EDIT** : 1

**[Statuscake](https://www.statuscake.com/)** is also one good option.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Harsh! We have Istio enabled. We have graph for Istio service, workloads etc. I can see the list of services here which are mostly ending with svc.cluster.local. Can you suggest which graph metrics is used to monitor service and how I can add alerts manager?

Comment: https://github.com/collabnix/dockerlabs/blob/master/kubernetes/beginners/Kubernetes_monitoring_alerting/alert_manager_on_K8.md